# Create Array in JavaScript From Comma Delimited String

Tags: javascript

Thanks in advance for any help. I've searched many articles and can't seem to figure this out.

I have a control that has a Value property that can be set like this from JS:
  `myControl.value(["8C65416E-DD68-4AF1-952B-2370D1D1F38B", "00EA79CB-6D5B-4A49-8CE4-32F19D88F6D8"]);`

This works perfectly fine.

I have a string coming from a database that looks like this:

```
myString = "8C65416E-DD68-4AF1-952B-2370D1D1F38B", "00EA79CB-6D5B-4A49-8CE4-32F19D88F6D8"
```

I am trying to set the controls value using the string, like this:

```
    myControl.value(myString);`
    OR like myControl.value([myString]);
```

I have tried to create an array, variations of split, etc. but can't seem to fine the magic touch. The string is already formatted for me with double quotes, commas, etc. Seems very simple, just can't seem to get it.

Comment: What *exactly* is `myString` and where is it coming from?  Why is the comma ***outside*** of the quotes?  What you have is `myString = 'a', 'b';` which sets `myString` to `'a'` (and ignores the `'b'`).

Comment: myString is coming from a database. I have it as variable being passed into the Javascript function, like  function MyFucntion(myString) { ... }

Comment: Um, that is not a single string....

Comment: You have a string that literally contains `myString = "8C65416E-DD68-4AF1-952B-2370D1D1F38B", "00EA79CB-6D5B-4A49-8CE4-32F19D88F6D8"` ? Or what do you mean ? Because `"8C65416E-DD68-4AF1-952B-2370D1D1F38B", "00EA79CB-6D5B-4A49-8CE4-32F19D88F6D8"` is not a string.

Comment: It is actually `myString = '"8C65416E-DD68-4AF1-952B-2370D1D1F38B", "00EA79CB-6D5B-4A49-8CE4-32F19D88F6D8"'` or `myString = "8C65416E-DD68-4AF1-952B-2370D1D1F38B, 00EA79CB-6D5B-4A49-8CE4-32F19D88F6D8"`

Comment: @DanielG: How is that function called, then?  How are you accessing this database?

Comment: yes...it is literally as I posted it

Comment: @DanielG: Can you do `console.log(myString);`?  That should help us all with the confusion here.  As you posted it is probably not actually what you have.

Comment: *"yes...it is literally as I posted it"* Than you can not do it since it is a comma operator.

Comment: Please review [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: "8C65416E-DD68-4AF1-952B-2370D1D1F38B", "00EA79CB-6D5B-4A49-8CE4-32F19D88F6D8" is the exact string. One string...

Comment: So it is not literally how you posted it? so use split() or match?

Comment: So the comma *and* single quotes are ***part*** of the string?  If so, then you can use `.spilt()` to turn it into an array (and then strip off the quotes later).  Something like `myArray = myString.split(/,\s?/).map((v)=>v.replace(/"/g, ''))`.

Comment: Rocket...you are the man. That did the trick .Much obliged sir.

Comment: ***Why*** is that you exact string?  ***Why*** are the quotes included?  Can you just have your database give you a JSON string?

Comment: I'll check with the DBA and see....working with what he gave me. You approach worked though. How do I make it the Answer?

Comment: I *guess* I can post it as an answer... but it seems someone else posted a *better* answer, have you tried that one?

Comment: @DanielG: If you are getting a string like you have, then someone somewhere is probably somehow doing something wrong.

Comment: lol...I'll let them know. I think he thought he was doing me a favor. The other Answer worked too....sincere thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is sort of like an array, you can use JSON.parse.

```js
var myString = '"8C65416E-DD68-4AF1-952B-2370D1D1F38B", "00EA79CB-6D5B-4A49-8CE4-32F19D88F6D8"';
var myArr = JSON.parse("[" + myString + "]");
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, epascarello.